# I am trying to pull images from object in an array using images.innerHTML = "<>" and I am having hard time trying to figure it out

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon Smart people!

I am trying to create a multiple-question app using javaScript. I am a little bit stuck and I would like your guidance. I am trying to place an image from an object in an array and I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this. It keeps saying undefined when I looked in the console. Can you tell me how I can go about this? Thank you!

```js
const questions = [
    {
      question: 'What is the first ship Luffy has accuired',
      imgSrc: "assets/pictures/sunnyGoMary.gif",
      answers: [
        { text: 'Sunny Go Mary', correct: true },
        { text: 'Victory Hunter', correct: false },
        { text: 'The Baratle', correct: false}, 
        { text: 'Polar Tang', correct: false}
      ]
    },
    {
      question: 'What is the town where Luffy is from?',
      imgSrc: "assets/pictures/LuffysHome.gif",
      answers: [
        { text: 'Shells Town', correct: false },
        { text: 'Shimotsuki Village', correct: false },
        { text: 'Foosha Village', correct: true },
        { text: 'Baratie', correct: false }
      ]
    },
    {
      question: `Pick the one that is NOT Luffy's Gear 4`,
      imgSrc: "assets/pictures/gear4.gif",
      answers: [
        { text: 'Snakeman', correct: false },
        { text: 'Baloon', correct: true },
        { text: 'Tankman', correct: false },
        { text: 'Boundman', correct: false }
      ]
    },
]

function showQuestion(question) {
  questionElement.innerText = question.question
  images.innerHTML = "<img src= questions.imgSrc>";
  question.answers.forEach(answer => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.innerText = answer.text
    button.classList.add('btn')
    if (answer.correct) {
      button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
    }
    button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
    answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
  })
}
```

Comment: The resulting `innerHTML` would be `<img src= questions.imgSrc>`, which isn't valid. Try using [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 1):

this line

```
images.innerHTML = "<img src= questions.imgSrc>";
```

should be instead - pay attention to "question" without "s" as well

```
images.innerHTML = `<img src="${question.imgSrc}">`;
```

but from security perspective - I would avoid using "innerHTML"

Comment: Fortunately, I've avoided using `innerHTML` for no reason. I didn't know there was a security risk. Thank you for the information. I would like to share a link about innerHTML security for those who didn't know about it like me: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use string concatenation, or [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to interpolate value.

```js
// template string
images.innerHTML = `<img src="${questions.imgSrc}" alt=""/>`;

// plain string concatenation
images.innerHTML = '<img src="' + questions.imgSrc + '" alt=""/>';
```

There is also [`String.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) method, but it will complicate things in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, and the provided example doesn't have any `console.log` so is difficult to understand what is printed `undefined` in the console.

Anyway, the main problem is the concatenation of the string into the HTML of the `images` variable. You're not concatenating the string properly, but using an entire string.

The solution in Javascript is

```
images.innerHTML = "<img src=\"" + questions.imgSrc + ">"
```

or in **ES6**

```
images.innerHTML = `<img src="${questions.imgSrc}">`
```

See [more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)